# how to do two differential equations at the same time

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A mouse runs around a $6m$ long circular table at $2$ m/s, starting at the right-most location of the table.

A cat is placed at a location on the table (near center) and paces straight towards the mouse, such that if the mouse were to stand still in shock, the cat would catch it in five seconds.

So I was thinking about how to do it but then I would need to do a differential equation for $x$ and another for $y$ which would be really complicated. I was hoping you could do this with complex number?

So then I would have $\displaystyle \frac{dz}{dt}=0.2(z-3e^{\frac{1}{6}it})$.

Am I like allowed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but I don't believe your differential equation is quite correct.  Presumably, you are letting $\ z\ $ be the position of the cat, and taking $\ 3e^{\frac{it}{6}}$ to be the position of the mouse at time $\ t\ $.  With that understanding, there seems to me to be the following problems with your formulation.

- The circumference of the table is $\ 6\pi\ $m, so if the mouse runs at $2$ m/s, it will take $\ 3\pi\ $s to complete a full circuit.  But if you substitute $\ t=3\pi $ into $\ 3e^{\frac{it}{6}}$, you get $\ 3e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$, which is only one quarter of the way around the circle.  To get the position of the mouse correct, you need the coefficient $\ \dot\theta\ $ of $\ it\ $ in $\ 3e^{it\dot\theta}$ to be the mouse's angular velocity in radians/s.
- The direction of $\ z-3e^{it\dot\theta}$ is *away* from the mouse, whereas you require $\ \displaystyle\frac{dz}{dt}\ $ to be directed *towards* the mouse.

Comment: I think what he meant is that the cat's speed towards the mouse is equal to 1/5 of the distance. and it says near the center, not necessarily at the center

Comment: @Saketh Malyala Thank you.  That seems to make more sense, although I don't think it's entirely clear from the way it's stated.

Comment: ooh i see. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

If you're attempting to express both variables, you can use complex numbers. It's especially useful since you have a mouse going around the table. However, to solve the differential equation, the second term of the result may not be so clean.

Comment: Ohh i see. it's okay though, i am only trying to verify the differential equation. i was thinking 0.2 because that's the speed based on the difference in position between cat and mosue